# How can I preserve hardlinks with tar while creating archives of multiple folders?

Tags: tar, hard-link

I have multiple subfolders and some of them contain hardlinks to other subfolders:

```
# mkdir /tmp/data
# mkdir /tmp/foo
# mkdir /tmp/foo/bar
# mkdir /tmp/foo/baz
# truncate -s 10M /tmp/foo/bar/file1
# ln /tmp/foo/bar/file1 /tmp/foo/baz/file1
# truncate -s 10M /tmp/foo/baz/file2
# ls -lah /tmp/foo/bar/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  60 Aug 18 13:22 ./
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root  80 Aug 18 13:22 ../
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 10M Aug 18 13:22 file1
# ls -lah /tmp/foo/baz/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  80 Aug 18 13:23 ./
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root  80 Aug 18 13:22 ../
-rw-rw-rw- 2 root root 10M Aug 18 13:22 file1
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10M Aug 18 13:23 file2
```

If I create a tar of the root folder, it preserves the hardlinks:

```
# tar -cf /tmp/foo.tar /tmp/foo
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: Removing leading `/' from hard link targets
# tar -tvf /tmp/foo.tar
drwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2021-08-18 13:22 tmp/foo/
drwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2021-08-18 13:23 tmp/foo/baz/
-rw-rw-rw- root/root  10485760 2021-08-18 13:23 tmp/foo/baz/file2
-rw-rw-rw- root/root  10485760 2021-08-18 13:22 tmp/foo/baz/file1
drwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2021-08-18 13:22 tmp/foo/bar/
hrw-rw-rw- root/root         0 2021-08-18 13:22 tmp/foo/bar/file1 link to tmp/foo/baz/file1
```

But if I do the same with each subfolder, they can't be preserved as tar does not know that the first archive already contains the file:

```
# tar -cf /tmp/bar.tar /tmp/foo/bar
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: Removing leading `/' from hard link targets
# tar -cf /tmp/baz.tar /tmp/foo/baz
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: Removing leading `/' from hard link targets
# tar -tvf /tmp/bar.tar
drwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2021-08-18 13:22 tmp/foo/bar/
-rw-rw-rw- root/root  10485760 2021-08-18 13:22 tmp/foo/bar/file1
# tar -tvf /tmp/baz.tar
drwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2021-08-18 13:23 tmp/foo/baz/
-rw-rw-rw- root/root  10485760 2021-08-18 13:23 tmp/foo/baz/file2
-rw-rw-rw- root/root  10485760 2021-08-18 13:22 tmp/foo/baz/file1
```

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot preserve a hardlink to another file that is outside the archive

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, hard links aren’t links to other files; each link is a directory entry pointing to the target inode. So there’s no notion of `tmp/foo/bar/file1` being a link to `tmp/foo/baz/file1`, in the file system.

`tar` notices that the files are linked to the same inode, if it stores them in the archive, and as a space-saving optimisation, stores the second and later files it encounters as links to the first (this is also useful so that `tar` can restore the state as it was when archived). This can only happen if the files are stored in the same archive, at the same time.

Technically, it is possible to create an archive storing a link to a file which isn’t in the archive: create the archive with both files, and then delete the file stored *as a file* from the archive.

Comment: Why hasn't this been upvoted more? Provides the technical details to understand the "why" ...